# Manual captcha solving library?

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha

I am working on a simple php **scraper** , the problem is that some of the websites I need to scrape have a captcha I need to solve, I used some services before, but since this is a small project I'd like to solve the captchas manually.

Is there a library I could use to simplify this? I mean the service I used had a library, where I just sent the image to their server and they gave me back the captcha solved, now I am looking for some library that would do something like that but it needs to have the part that shows the captcha and allow me to solve it **manually** and then pass it back to my app.

Comment: They included captcha just because they don't want people like you stole their data. It is illegal.

Comment: Generally people use a capture because they *don't* want people scraping their site.

Comment: You may have to build this yourself and integrate it with your scraper. It's not entirely trivial to do but not impossible either

Comment: 1) Then don't scrape those sites 2) How can a library solve CAPTCHAs manually?

Comment: lol the captcha's are there for a reason!

Comment: @BoltClock The library emails the captchas to a dedicated team of offshore operators. Their prices are really quite reasonable. :)

Comment: Why don't you use Amazon Mechanical Turk? :D But seriously, there's a reason they put a captcha there.

Comment: @Peter Nothing you could be doing is worth answering by this community.

Comment: The captchas are in a search box, i dont think it's there to prevent scrapping but to prevent abuse, I need to run less than 20 request.

Comment: `CircumventingCAPTCHA === Abuse`

Comment: What kind of abuse besides scraping could you prevent with a captcha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's actually trivial to do. On the PHP site of things, you just need to send the image or img URL to a separate process. exec() would usually not be an option, so I'd suggest a inetd-process and fsockopen:

```
$f = fsockopen("localhost", 55555, $errno, $errstr, 30);
fwrite($f, $IMAGE_URL);
$captcha = fread($f, 100);
```

Register a script for port 55555 and on invocation make it read the URL from stdin. Display the image in a window, wait for keyboard input, return said input over stdout (socket). Don't forget `set_time_limit` though.

I'd recommend a Tcl/Tk script, but am too lazy to write one.